# How to apply formatting to data feeding AdvancedDataGrid in ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, formatting, advanceddatagrid, htmltext

I'm using the Halo AdvancedDataGrid component, in which the default itemEditor for each column is mx.controls.TextInput.

For example, the data provider is:
[CODE][Bindable]
private var labelsGridArray:Array = [ { tag:"apple" }, { tag:"*banana" }, { tag:"carrot" } ];[/CODE]
And the AdvancedDataGrid definition is:
[CODE][/CODE]

If a String from the dataprovider Array is preceded by an asterisk - as is the case for banana in this example - the String needs to be surrounded by square brackets and be displayed in a grey colour.

I tried to do the following:
[CODE]

A colleague told me about using the AdvancedDataGridColumn's labelFunction attribute. I tried that but was unable to do the following assignment (the id of the column is 'tag'):
[CODE]tag.itemEditor.htmlText = formattedText;[/CODE]

I get error "Access of possibly undefined property htmlText through a reference with static type mx.core:IFactory.

I tried to both explicitly extract the TextInput itemEditor (like I did for the override set data) AND use the labelFunction, but I couldn't get both to be in the correct scopes.

Your help is much appreciated,
Bonnie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating your own itemRenderer / itemEditor.

This would be your datagrid:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        [Bindable] private var labelsGridArray:Array = [ { tag:"apple" }, { tag:"*banana" }, { tag:"carrot" } ];
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<mx:DataGrid dataProvider="{labelsGridArray}" >
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Name" itemRenderer="NameItemRenderer"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

And this would be your itemRenderer/editor (NameItemRenderer.mxml)

```
<s:MXDataGridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                      xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                      xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                      focusEnabled="true">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        override public function set data(value:Object):void{
            super.data = value;
            if(value.tag.indexOf("*")!= -1){
                lblData.text = "[" + value.tag + "]";
                lblData.setStyle("color",0xFF0000);
            }
            else{
                lblData.text = "" + value.tag ;
                lblData.setStyle("color",0x000000);
            }
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:Label id="lblData" top="0" left="0" right="0" bottom="0"/>
```

I have used a normal mx:Datagrid and a spark MXDataGridItemRenderer for this, but the way it works will be the same for the AdvancedDataGrid. All you need to do is override set data()

Cheers

Comment: Thanks Dennis! Both for your quick reply AND providing me with something that works. I'm still a little shaky with creating separate itemRenderers/itemEditors. Unfortunately, I cannot give you votes b/c it says "Vote up requires 15 reputations". Pls let me know if I can do anything about this.

Comment: This is a little embarrassing. I'm not very used to stackoverflow website yet. How do I accept this answer as helpful? I'm not allowed to click on the arrow above the '0'. Also, I'm having trouble getting a colour code. Elsewhere in my application, I picked gray48, and I had to use the hexadecimal code of #7A7A7A. For the Label.setStyle function, I have to use the code starting with '0x'. But searching around the Internet, this code is also called the hexadecimal code! Any ideas about how I can find the equivalent of #7A7A7A?

Comment: 0x7a7a7a should do the trick, it is merely an integer value instead of a hex string. You can indeed not upvote when below a certain reputation treshold. However i believe you can always 'accept' my answer as the solution to your question. For more information, see the faq page. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. I found out how to accept your answer by clicking on the checkmark to the left. I also found out that I got 1 vote for my question. I'm on my way up. I do have one question about the code that you supplied: if(value.tag.indexOf("*")!= -1). This didn't work for me in Flex 4/AS 3. I had to use if(value.tag.indexOf("*")==0), meaning the * is found in the first position of the String. What's the interpretation of your code?

Comment: It Looks for the index of the first occurrence of * and if it is not found, you will have the default -1 value. So basically i am just testing if the tag contains a * anywhere.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks again for all your help and very good response times. I'm happy to say that you helped me wrap up one user story .